# Value of a json object is updated while printing before making changes to one of its property in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
// declaring a variable
let var1 = {
    item: "bat",
    sport: "cricket"
};

// printing the values without any changes
console.log(var1);
console.log(var1.item);

// printing the values after changing the item value
var1.item = "ball";
console.log(var1);
console.log(var1.item);
```

The output of the above program is:
 [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaeCr.png)

Can someone explain the reason for this output. Why does the value of var1 get updated when printing before making change to var1.item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time but it is the value of the object at the moment you click it open.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

To capture the state of the object as is you could do `console.log(JSON.stringify(var1))`

Comment: Thanks Jan for the prompt reply. I tried the code with your suggestion and it gives me the correct output now.

Comment: No worries. A viable alternative if you're only interested in primitive properties (which is probably clearer to read and still navigable in the console) is to use the spread operator `console.log({...var1})` to create a copy of the object. However, properties which are objects are still subject to change.